# pdfLatex output has "Copyright (c) AMS". How to remove?

Tags: pdftex, strings, output, copyright

Compiling with `pdflatex`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
1
\end{document}
```

and postprocessing with

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=b.pdf a.pdf
```

and running `strings can.pdf | grep "American"` which finds text inside the PDF including "American" returns:

```
Copyright (c) 1997, 2009 American Mathematical Society (<http://www.ams.org>), with Reserved Font Name CMR10.CMR10Computer Modern
```

Notice that the text appears after postprocessing.

With other tools, I can compress the PDF further. Then this becomes the second longest string in the PDF. Is there any way to remove it (or is that a bug)? This PDF is for my personal use so it should be legal to remove that. I'm chasing redundant bytes. (Though isn't how a copyright text is introduced by default, which isn't even viewable with strings, creepy?)

I can replace the text with random characters. What I'm looking for is a way to save space.

XeLatex doesn't have this problem.

Comment: the copyright notice is from the font, cmr10.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So the only to avoid should be to use XeTeX. (Please tell me if you know how to prevent the font from being added other than switching to XeTeX). Otherwise if you add this as an answer I can accept it, `pdffonts` shows an embedded font named `TTZPQU+CMR10` so you must be right.

Comment: well you need some font if you want to get some text. And I'm rather sure that also the opentype latin modern font used by xetex has some copyright included, only that it is more compressed.

Comment: Found a way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798374 suggests adding to `-dNoOutputFonts` to GhostScript to, include text without fonts as vectors. Thanks, you pointed me to the correct direction.

Comment: if the fonts are not embedded the viewer will have to use some fallback, which can lead to wrong output. I don't think that this makes sense nowadays.